# Can I eliminate use of hidden form fields in html to pass data between pages where the data is row id of all table rows

Tags: php, html, forms, session-variables, hidden

I am developing an web app in which user should click on a link dislayed next to an order to generate an order details pdf
The page showing the orders by a particular user as a table with two columns:- time of order and pdf link for each order is having this snippet

```
echo '<table class="table"><tr>
<th>Order Submitted on</th>
<th>Get Details</th>
</tr>';
while ($row = $ordersByUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['timestamp'].'</td>';

    echo '<td><form method="POST" action="generateorderpdf.php">
    <input type ="hidden" name="orderid" value='.$row['id'].'>
    <input type="submit" value="CLICK" class="btn btn-dark">
    </form></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I am storing the primary key of each order

```
$row['id']
```

in a hidden field which is then sent to the generateOrderPdf.php page to generate the order pdf through a form using post method. My problem is that users can change the hidden input field using some browser developer tools and generate pdfs for other users which i definity don't want users to do (and its the reason why i am sending post request to the generate pdf page since anyone can edit the get url and see other people's orders). So is there any way in which I can eliminate the dependency on hidden input fields to send order id to the generateOrderPdf.php page?

I've read that i can use sessions to store sensitive data which then eliminates the need to use hidden form fields but I don't know is it even possible to use session variables to solve this problem and if possible how since this is a table of data?

Comment: The script that generates the PDF should check that the order ID belongs to the user.

Comment: You can't really use session variables for this, because the user needs to be able to specify a particular order. A session variable wouldn't know which button the user clicked on.

Comment: Does the user have to log in to the site?  If so you should have his "user id" or some other way of verifying they are logged in.  When generating the PDF you need to check if that order belongs to that user.

Comment: @Barmer Yes exactly the session variable will not know which button the user clicked so I am dependent on the hidden input field to store the order id.

Comment: @mathius1 Yes the user has to login to the site and I am using the user_id as a foriegn key in the orders table to pull out the orders corresponding to a user. Ok so you're saying that i use the user_id to check whether the order really belongs to him/her in the generate pdf page. I never thought of checking the orderid in the generatepdfpage. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you *can* do this with a session variable.

Put all the order IDs in an array in the session. Instead of putting the order ID in the hidden input, put the array index.

```
$myorders = [];
$order_index = 0;
echo '<table class="table"><tr>
<th>Order Submitted on</th>
<th>Get Details</th>
</tr>';
while ($row = $ordersByUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $myorders[$order_index] = $row['id'];
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['timestamp'].'</td>';

    echo '<td><form method="POST" action="generateorderpdf.php">
    <input type ="hidden" name="orderid" value="'.$order_index.'">
    <input type="submit" value="CLICK" class="btn btn-dark">
    </form></td></tr>';
    $order_index++;
}
echo '</table>';
$_SESSION['myorders'] = $myorders;
```

Then in `generatorderpdf.php`, you use `$_SESSION['myorders'][$_POST['orderid']]` to get the order ID.